# Entity Framework Update - Overwrite values or not

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 to perform CRUD operations against my database. I have turned off the following properties:

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

My method to update a user object

```
    public void Edit(User user)
    {
        _context.Entry(user).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Ive retrieved:

```
User.Forename = Joe
User.Surname = Bloggs
```

Ive passed the user object to my edit method with

```
User.Forename = Joe
User.Surname = Bloggs
```

If I pass my user object to my Edit method but i haven't changed any of its properties, as above. Will the properties be over written in the database with the same value or will Entity Framework know the value hasn't changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you explicitly set the state to `Modified`, EF does send an update statement to the database even if none of the property values have changed.

If you don't want EF to update the database with the same values, you'll have to add logic to track whether the values have changed since you are setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false`.